# In Vim, how can I undo opening?

Tags: vim, undo, nerdtree

I started using NERDTree recently.

When I opened a file while having split window, the window of a new file was not I intended.
Consequently, I had lost my unsaved buffer by opening a file.

Is there any way to undo opening files or reopen my unsaved buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go back to the previous file in a buffer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have modified my question a bit but it is still the answer.I didn't have to undo right?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't lost anything (yet), the buffer was *hidden*. Since it is the *alternate buffer* of that window, you can just switch back via `<C-^>`. You'll also find it in the buffer list of `:ls` (with a `h` prefix for hidden), from which you can re-edit it via its buffer number, e.g. `:buffer 42` or `:sbuf 42`.

If there are unsaved changes, Vim will prompt you on `:quit` (unless you provide a `!` to it).